# Uploading a .csv to BigQuery

Tags: google-bigquery

I am trying to upload a .csv to BigQuery that I downloaded onto my computer. The file is over 100mb, which is over the limit that BigQuery puts on local uploads. So I put it into cloud storage and when I copied the gsutil URI and tried to put that into BigQuery, it says that Bucket names may only contain lowercase letters, numbers, dashes, underscores, and dots. The problem is that my gsutil URI does contain dashes and it will not upload onto BigQuery. I need some help in figuring out how to upload .csv files over 100mb into BigQuery.

Comment: can you add an example URI that you are using?